# What is this date format? 2021-10-04T08:19:54.000+04:00

Tags: php, date

And how can I covert it to 'd.m.Y H:i:s' with php?

```
gmdate('d.m.Y H:i:s', '2021-10-04T08:19:54.000+04:00')
```

did not help

Comment: Split the string and extract relevant information.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601, and `gmdate` takes a _timestamp_ so it shouldn't be surprising that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format is ISO8601 if I'm not mistaken. PHP can parse this using the default `DateTime` class:

```php
$date = new DateTime('2021-10-04T08:19:54.000+04:00');
$date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: In the code I posted, the `$date` variable is never converted to a string, so the error must be in something you added. Maybe you're trying to echo `$date` itself, without the `->format` call

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose just use the native `DateTime` class. It can interpret several formats. Yours looks like ISO8601.

```
echo (new DateTime('2021-10-04T08:19:54.000+04:00'))->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

its ISO 8601 date and you can format this easyly with dateTime or carbon.
You can find more info here https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php